# Flex ComboBox - Refresh dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a combobox to list the contents of a folder.

With a button click I use that combobox.selectedItem to delete that folder. After I delete the data is still in the combobox. How do I go about refreshing that combobox?

Comment: Remove it from the dataProvider

Comment: @RIAstar Post that as a formal answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: I was trying to reset the .prompt as well...do I need to think about just refreshing the entire canvas?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Sometimes I'm just too lazy. Thanks for the kick in the but ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArrayLists and ArrayCollections (whichever you use as a 'dataProvider') both dispatch [CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/CollectionEvent.html#COLLECTION_CHANGE) events to notify the List component (or CombBox in this case) that an item was added or removed.

So basically all you need to do, is removing the item from the dataProvider and the ComboBox will refresh automatically.

```
myComboBox.dataProvider.removeItemAt(myComboBox.selectedIndex);
```

(for this example code I'm assuming you're talking about a Spark ComboBox which only takes ILists as a dataProvider)

Comment: @Bungdaddy Doesn't matter. The example should work just the same, except you won't get code hinting in FlashBuilder because mx:ComboBox' data type is Object. The difference is it's being converted to an IList behind the scenes.

Comment: is it possible to reset the prompt as well. After your above example I added myComboBox.prompt = "Select New" -- doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: @Bungdaddy Perhaps you still have a selected item in the ComboBox, which would prevent the prompt from showing. Try setting `selectedIndex = -1`

Comment: Thanks a ton, that issue has been haunting in so many places on my UI. Greatly appreciated!